# Keep variable array in JS to use on other pages

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a list when only a particular page is visited JS/jQuery. I then need to access this list when I visit other pages and the variables in them. How do I store it?

I thought by defining it outside the function this would be okay...?

```
var colours = [];

//make the list
$( document ).ready(function() {
    if ( window.location.href == 'http://something/anotherthing/') {
        colours.push(orange);
        colours.push(purple);
        colours.push(green);
        colours.push(magenta);
        }
    }
});

//want to access the list here!
$( document ).ready(function() {
    //need to access the colours as defined above
    var index = 3;
    var using_colour = colours[index];
});
```

I realise I keep setting `var colours = [];` which is why it's coming back blank for views that aren't 'http://something/anotherthing/'. If I move it I get

> cannot read property of undefined

Basically, how do I create a variable list **once** and then access it later...?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried using cookies or web-storage?

Comment: [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

Comment: Every page has a separate windows object so the variables you define in one will never be available in other. Use cookies, sessions etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to clarify how to use localStorage, it will be available across a website even after reloading the page or navigating to another page as long as it's in the same domain.

Example usage:

```
if(localStorage["colours"] === undefined) {
   localStorage["colours"] = ["orange", "purple", "green", "magenta"];
}

var colours = localStorage["colours"].split(',');
```

Also, if you need to store `Objects`, you can do so using `JSON.stringify` / `JSON.parse`:

```
localStorage["colours"] = JSON.stringify({ green: 'blue', purple: 'orange' });
var colours = JSON.parse(localStorage["colours"]);
```

Comment: what is the split() for here - it is an array?

Comment: When accessing it from `localStorage` it's returned as a `string` `"orange,purple,green,magenta"`

Comment: works absolutely great - relieved I didn't have to install any plugins. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using jQuery plugin (jQuery cookies) for this, you can get the same from https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

First set your cookies

```
var colours = [];

//make the list
$(document).ready(function() {
        if (window.location.href == 'http://something/anotherthing/') {
            colours.push(orange);
            colours.push(purple);
            colours.push(green);
            colours.push(magenta);

            Cookies.set('ColoursArray', colours);
        }
});
```

After you can access this into other page load event

```
$(function() {
        if(Cookies.get('ColoursArray') != 'undefined' ){
     var colours = Cookies.get('ColoursArray'); --> this is your array
    }
});
```

Comment: Just a heads up, you can achieve something similar without any jquery/plugins just by using localstorage

Comment: yes it can be achieved with local storage as well, but cookies will expire as soon as you close your browser unless you give explicit expiry

Comment: Yes sorry I know cookies can do that too which you can do locally rather than having to use jquery or a plugin is what I meant

Answer (score -3):

you should create a separate script tag in main template HTML/PHP file:

`<script type="text/javascript"> var colors = []; </script>`

and include this above all your `script` tags. But below core JS files.

Comment: I still get a variable is undefined error with this @Akshay Prakash

Comment: When you view the page source this variable should be on top of all script tags especially in which you are using colors variable. Ok, I guess, for each request the complete script page loads, this will re-initialise all the scripts. I suggest you use cookie.